# Unable to find JAVA_HOME

Tags: linux, unix, java-home

I copied the latest java 1.8 to a red hat Linux server. I ran the command java -version and it returned version 1.7.0_131. I updated .bashrc and the jre to the latest version 1.8. When I run the command version java -version it still says its version 1.7.0_31. What I need to know where is this being picked up from. I have checked .profile, .bashrc and JAVA_HOME they all are pointing to the location where I update to 1.8. Greatly appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type `which java` and you will probably see (at least after you have followed all the symlinks) that the Java executable is taken from somewhere else than your newly set JAVA_HOME. You need to create the appropriate symlinks to version 1.8, too, like this:

```
ln -s /your/path/to/v18/bin/java /usr/bin/java
```

Be aware that existing applications might use the 1.7 Java version and you might break them when you set `/usr/bin/java` (or whatever path the `which` command showed you) to the 1.8 version.

Fyi, JAVA_HOME is not meant to be used by your shell to locate the *Java* command. It is to be used by other software that require Java to know where to find it.

Comment: ...which is a symlink. Check where it is going with ``ls -al /usr/bin/java``

Comment: That worked. Thanks. when i do which java i get /usr/bin/java/. What do i need to do to see this result "/opt/adobe/java/jre/bin/java" when i do which java?

Comment: `PATH=/opt/adobe/java/jre/bin:$PATH`. BTW, consider using `type java` instead of `which java` -- the former is built into bash, the latter requires running an external command.

Comment: @SGR29 either add it to your path like Charles Duffy suggested or create a symlink like in my post. One of which might make more sense regarding your system, but it can't be determined from here. Charles Duffy, thanks for the hint with _type_.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks, Guys!!

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this once

```
export JAVA_HOME=/jdk/path
```

If you use it continuously, add the above code to your .bashrc file or profile. Then open new terminal or run below code

```
source .bashrc
```